# How do I check if a string is present in a webpage using jsoup?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        linksOnPage = doc.select("h2.filmibeat-myshow-movie > a[href][title]");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    //Log.e("Value", txt);
    for(Element link : linksOnPage) {
        //Log.e("fsdsd", link.attr("title"));
        if (link.attr("title").contains(txt)) { // The search I tried
            final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toast.cancel();
                }
            },1000);

        }

    }
}
```

**contains(txt) method doesn't always work with all inputs and I always get a "NO" toast. I want to check if the input txt is present in the web page.Please Help!**

Comment: `link.attr("title").contains(txt)` using this line you check if text is present in the links' title, but not `in a web page` as you ask in the question. Do you need to check only links' titles, or entire web page?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'm parsing the web page for movie listings in local theatres. I've successfully parsed the movies which I can in the Logcat output. But the contains method doesn't work and always gives a bummer  toast.

Comment: method `.contains` works correctly. I think that there is some problem with the input. Try logging what you check in `.contains`, and see the log output. I think that you'll see where is the problem. Also you can post the URL where you get HTML from, and the input that you've tried to do, and I'll check it manually.

Comment: @VladMatvienko String url ="http://www.filmibeat.com/movie_listings/Chennai.html";

Comment: and what you try to `.contains`?

Comment: A movie name inside that url. (Say John Wick). I'm getting this in logcat. Can you tell me how to give a Yes toast if there's atleast one True? false

E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
E/dfdfd: false
 E/dfdfd: true

Comment: what is that `false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: false E/dfdfd: true `?

Comment: Logcat output of contains.(). I'm getting a true for what I'm searching for. How to write a condition for the same?

Comment: show the code, which gives you this logcat

Comment: @VladMatvienko for(Element link : linksOnPage) {
                
                Log.e("dfdfd", String.valueOf(link.attr("title").contains(txt))); //This is the code
                if (link.attr("title").contains(txt)) {

Comment: then your code is correct - `if (link.attr("title").contains(txt)) {` should work if the txt matches title.